# Return inside a method one or two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

Its not duplicated i have read all and nothing suite in my case so please read it and answer it.I have two arrays.One is Vehicle and the other is pin.This is a part of code  and it is **only** the method.

**First question :**

> if i have declare the arrays on the same main out of
>   this method the way i pass them on the method is right?With other words the parameteres
>   are good or need (int vehicle[],int pin[]) or something else?

**Second question** +=

> i dont know what it does but i think that in  the array pin it takes
>   as an ecample the  pin[1] cost has 10.The number 10 is taken by
>   getcostosvehicle();(we put it from userinput) so when the array fills
>   and it hasnt any slot then the costs will be finished.As a result will
>   have lets say the ended slot is 20 in pin[20] lets say it has 350.The
>   return statement will give us only the last cost?It would be better to
>   write return pin[i]; so in that way it will return all the pin with
>   the whole costs of each one slot,am i right?

**Third question**

> On this code and that i want to write me as an answer could you return
>   two arrays?I mean return pin[i],vehicle[i]; not only return pin[i];.If
>   yes,could you do an answer and doesnt need to  fill in the vehicle
>   array.Just to show me if this can happen.

```
public static int  getallcosts(vehicle[],pin[]) {

        int costos = 0;

        for(int i =0; i < pin.length; i++) {
            costos += pin[i].getcostosvehicle();
        }

        return costos;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to show some compilable (and thus less confusing) code.

Comment: why confusing code?In first line it is just the name getallcosts and the parameteres of the two arrays.In second is a variable and after i fill the array and in the end i returning it.Maybe to do comments?i think it doesnt need too.If you want i can do it

Comment: One thing that's confusion: is `vehicle` the name of the array or the type of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i have declare the arrays on the same main out of this method the way i pass them on the method is right?With other words the parameteres are good or need (int vehicle[],int pin[]) or something else?

I'm not sure I understand you correctly but *of course* `getallcosts(vehicle[],pin[])` won't compile, i.e. you need to define the *type* of the arrays (or the names if `vehicle` and `pin` would actually be the types).

> It would be better to write return pin[i]; so in that way it will return all the pin with the whole costs of each one slot,am i right?

No, you can only have *one* return value. If you want to return multiple values then you need to wrap them in an object (array, list, pojo, etc.).

> On this code and that i want to write me as an answer could you return two arrays?

See the part above: if you want to return multiple arrays you need to add them so some object and return that object. Since you didn't provide the types for the arrays I'll use another example:

```
class Result {
  String[] strings;
  int[] numbers;
}

Result someMethod() {
  Result r = new Result();
  r.strings = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
  r.numbers= new int[]{1,2,3};
  return r;
}
```

Comment: the r what it is?basicaly Result r = new Result();  you calling the method? you create a method ?

Comment: with 'Result()' you're calling the default constructur of 'Result' class.

Comment: on the method Result someMethod(){ } i think it would be Result someMethod(string[] Strings,numbers[] int){}.Am i wrong?

Comment: I'm basically calling a constructor which is a special kind of method (read it up in any decent Java tutorial).

Comment: ooo i  was thinking it was a method ! sorry :D yes i knew it but i didnt catch it my mind was goind to method

Comment: No, it would be `Result someMethod(String[] strings, int[] numbers)` (or whatever you want to use) - as should be clear from any decent Java tutorial as well (i.e. type before name etc.).

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**

If you are calling a method (so you're not defining it) yuo can write parameters as you do, without type. 
Otherwise you need to specify type. In this case you are defining a new method so you need to specify type of parameters.

**Second question:**

'+=' it's like write

```
costos = costos + pin[i].getcostosvehicle();
```

So you will add to the current value of 'costos' the 'costos' of vehicle retrieved by 'getcostosvehicle()';

**Third question:**

As i know you can't return two Objects of any type in return statement.
So you'll need to reorganize your code to do operation first on an array and return it and then on the other one and return it.
For example you can do a method that have as parameter a generica array do some logic inside and then return it. You will call this method for the first array and then for the second.

Example:

```
public int[] method(int[] array){
  /*do something
  */
  return array;
}
```

Then you will call:

```
firstArray = method(firstArray);
secondArray = method(secondArray);
```

If you want more, or i have to change something comment please.